# How to do POST for Object Data type?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jpa

I have the JSON data as below:

```
{
 "id": '123',
 "name": {
       "fname": "arav"
      }
}
```

I want to save name as json object. 
How do I do in JPA?
I am trying in Spring-boot application.

I am using apache-derby db (in-memory db)

```
@Entity
public class MyName{

@Id 
private String id;

@Lob
private Object name;

getter... setter... methods
}


{
    "timestamp": "2019-05-17T11:34:45.919+0000",
    "path": "/name/test",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.sql/java.sql.Blob",
    "trace": "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.sql/java.sql.Blob\r\n\tat org.hibernate.type.BlobType.getReplacement(BlobType.java:20)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType
```

Answer (score 0):

Well unless you use some special extension or type (such as jsonb or json type in postgres for instance), and as the json representation of an object is just a string representation, you should probably serialize the name LinkedHashMap instance to json string using a json library such like jackson and store the value on a varchar datatype column.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add one more annotations

```
    @Entity
    public class MyName{
    @Id 
    private String id;
   @ElementCollection
    @Lob
    private Object name;

    getter... setter... methods
    }
```

Comment: @Danne Why you are not using Hibernate Types ? Take a look on that ..that will help you to persists the JSON data

Comment: hi, hibernate types ? can you mention here ?